# How I get each cpu message in mutilprocessor computer with perf?

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, perf

My work is to measure each node in mutilprocessor computer (eg. 4 cores) using `perf`.  Including cache-misses, LLC-loads, LLC-load-misses, LLC-stores, LLC-store-misses and so forth and I only get the total statistic data.

Is there a way to  distinguish them?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of `perf` you could use a combination of the `-a` and `-C` switches.

From [kernel.org's perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Processor-wide_mode):

> The demonstration machine has only two CPUs, but we can limit to CPU 1.
>
> ```
>    perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u -a -C 1 sleep 5
>
>     Performance counter stats for 'sleep 5':
>
>     301,141,166 cycles
>     225,595,284 instructions             #      0.749 IPC
>
>     5.002125198  seconds time elapsed
> ```

So, if you have 4 processors, you could do:

```
perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u -a -C 0 sleep 5
perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u -a -C 1 sleep 5
perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u -a -C 2 sleep 5
perf stat -B -e cycles:u,instructions:u -a -C 3 sleep 5
```

Comment: yeah, but how can I know the message of every CPU when running my program in mutil CPUs in one command. in your way, I just grab data in CPU1.

Comment: To make my problem clear, what I want to know is that the specific process's statistics in per-cpu basis.

Comment: how about  “perf stat -a -A” the '- A' disable CPU count aggregation, I get 32 cpus data, but I only 4. what do you think about that?

Comment: And I double that running 4 instances of perf one for each processor and one instance running in 4 processor simultaneously are different situations.

Comment: oh, I find my computer having 32 cpus, sorry~

Comment: I don't have the -A switch, you probably have a newer / different version :).